# Check website responsiveness panel

Tags: css, plugins, responsive-design, markup

Does anyone know a special tool like in Patternlab (see screenshot) for checking responsiveness of your website. I know there are many services for this purpose but I need to deploy this thing on my server. Maybe there are some gulp packages for it?

[image]

I hope this question will be useful for many people.

Thanks

Comment: I use this sometimes: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: But it's an external service. I'm searching for plugin like implementation
Anyway thanks for a good tool

Answer (score 2):

I think to check better responsiveness Firefox is best 
press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
for responsive option

Comment: Of course I know this tool. Chrome is also good at that. 
But I need a plugin because I have to show it to my client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome, 
check Re:view extension here 
http://re-view.emmet.io/

In Safari you can use Responsive mode with alt + cmd + R